# angular js 2 basic setup issues

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular, tsd

I have PHP and JavaScript background and never worked with nodejs or angular js with full hand , just a basic understanding of these js.

I started to learn angular js 2 but find very difficulties to set up first example.

> node v 5.6.0 and npm version 3.7.2 on ubuntu 14.04

I am following [this article](http://blog.edenmsg.com/angular2-typescript-gulp-and-expressjs/) with a change -- that `tsd` has been deprecated so used `typings` instead of `tsd`. below is my folder structure.
[image: angular 2 set up]

But when I run `gulp buildServer` on terminal  it gives below errors

[image: Gulp Error]

I may be doing very basic error , kindly help me to solve this and if required more information then tell me.

**server.ts** has below code

```
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');
var port: number = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();

app.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')));
app.use('/libs', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'libs')));

var renderIndex = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}

app.get('/*', renderIndex);

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('This express app is listening on port:' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the type definitions for node and server-static.

```
typings install node --ambient --save
typings install serve-static --ambient --save
typings install mime --ambient --save
```

You need `mime` since `serve-static` relys on it.

Comment: Thanks , it removed the given error but gives 655 lines of errors showing `server/typings/main/ambient/node/node.d.ts(...,..): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier ......`

Comment: will you please see my new problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368497/angular-2-multiple-times-error-ts2300-duplicate-identifier

Answer (score 1):

It says `cannot find module 'path'` and then again with `http` and so on. Also errors with duplicate identifier in my experience are due to using old version of `npm` because since `npm v3.0` it tries to make [all dependencies flat](http://dailyjs.com/2015/06/26/npm-3/).

I'd try to `rm -rf node_modules`, install newest stable `node` and `npm`, run again `npm install` and then try running your `gulp`. Or at least check what are your `npm` and `node` versions.

Comment: my  npm version is 1.3.7 and nodejs version is v0.10.25 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have not much knowledge of node..my assumption is that this may be because there is `node_modules` folder but we haven't  write in the code there where is the express and other module in server.ts

Comment: That's pretty old, try to upgrade both and then re-run it. Typescript compiler looks into your `node_modules` directory by default, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: would that run over ubuntu 14.04 ? do i need to uninstall both node and npm?

Comment: I don't know how to install it on Ubuntu. Maybe have a look here https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions.

Comment: I have updated both node and npm but issues are still same. do i need to delete node_modules folder reside in the sample folder

Comment: I'd recommend removing the old `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.