# angular 2 multiple times error TS2300: Duplicate identifier

Tags: node.js, gulp, angular

system configuraions

- ubuntu 14.04
- node -v => v5.6.0
- npm -v =>  3.7.1
- typings latest version (don't know how to get version detail)

while working with angular2 first time on 
my folder **sample/server** structure is below

```
|-- server.js
|-- server.ts
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- typings
|   |-- browser
|   |   `-- ambient
|   |       |-- express
|   |       |   `-- express.d.ts
|   |       |-- mime
|   |       |   `-- mime.d.ts
|   |       |-- node
|   |       |   `-- node.d.ts
|   |       `-- serve-static
|   |           `-- serve-static.d.ts
|   |-- browser.d.ts
|   |-- main
|   |   `-- ambient
|   |       |-- express
|   |       |   `-- express.d.ts
|   |       |-- mime
|   |       |   `-- mime.d.ts
|   |       |-- node
|   |       |   `-- node.d.ts
|   |       `-- serve-static
|   |           `-- serve-static.d.ts
|   `-- main.d.ts
`-- typings.json
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
   "files": [
    "./server/typings/main.d.ts",
    "./server/server.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
        "node_modules", 
        // even used ../node_modules as the folder is located above this folder
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser"
  ]
}
```

#### typings.json

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "express": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts#d1f6bde13f2209be42e86c3686761e8bfcbb50a5",
    "mime": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/mime/mime.d.ts#d1f6bde13f2209be42e86c3686761e8bfcbb50a5",
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#aee0039a2d6686ec78352125010ebb38a7a7d743",
    "serve-static": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/serve-static/serve-static.d.ts#0fa4e9e61385646ea6a4cba2aef357353d2ce77f"
  }
}
```

#### gulpgile.js

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('log', function() {
  gutil.log('== My Log Task ==')
});

gulp.task('buildServer', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('./server/tsconfig.json');
    return gulp.src('./server/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./server'))
});
```

#### main.d.ts and browser.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/mime/mime.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/serve-static/serve-static.d.ts" />
```

when run

```
usernam@hostname:~/sample$ gulp buildServer
```

it gives 655 errors similar to below , referencing every line of node.d.ts

**server/typings/browser/ambient/node/node.d.ts(754,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'internal'.**

...
....

**server/typings/main/ambient/node/node.d.ts(1943,18): error TS2300:
Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.**

...

.....

**server/typings/main/ambient/serve-static/serve-static.d.ts(85,5):
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.**

and finally it's stops

```
[22:38:56] TypeScript: 655 semantic errors
[22:38:56] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

#### UPDATE

I notice it gives error first for *main/* folder than for *browser/* folder

my guess is that issue is with *gulpfile.js* ; 
 make below change in gulpfile.js

`return gulp.src('./server/**/*.ts')`  to return `gulp.src('./server/main/*.ts')`

then **gulp buildServer** runs but finished instantly.

- What does this `.js` do?
- Can **gulp.dest** and **gulp.src** pointed on same folder?

Please suggest what is the work around to fix this.I have seen over the web but couldn't find anything working for now.

Comment: `.js` files are compile and run by browser,and secondly `gulp.dest` is the destination path for the `.js` files which is taken from the `gulp.src` path may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including all `*.ts` files including the definition files try just including all `*.ts` files excluding **all** `*.d.ts` files except for `main.d.ts`.

```
gulp.src(['server/**/*.ts', '!server/**/*.d.ts', 'server/typings/main.d.ts'])
```

or (not 100% on how the ordering works in glob off the top of my head)

```
gulp.src(['server/**/*.ts', 'server/typings/main.d.ts', '!server/**/*.d.ts'])
```

**Update:** I ended up using `merge2` to combine two `gulp.src` streams.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var merge = require('merge2');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    var tsFiles = gulp.src('server/**/*.ts', '!server/typings/**');

    return merge(tsFiles, gulp.src('server/typings/main.d.ts'))
        .pipe(typescript(...));
});
```

Comment: This removed the error ; now gives semantics `error..server/server.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
server/server.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.
server/server.ts(3,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.
server/server.ts(6,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
server/server.ts(7,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
server/server.ts(10,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.`

Comment: I've actually just ran into this same issue. I believe it may be a bug with `gulp-typescript` but not 100% sure.

Comment: I've opened an issue in the gulp repo since it actually seems like a bug with `gulp.src`, feel free to follow it https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1525

Comment: I've updated my answer that seems to _fix_ the issue since the issue was closed without help

Comment: by doing this; gulp server start and finished within 3.43 seconds. this is not expected behaviour

Comment: Are you talking about it took 3.43 seconds to build the server or when you ran a different gulp task it took 3.43 seconds and then stopped?

Comment: I run `gulp buildServer` which is only single task in my gulfile.js ..it runs and finished within 3.43 second. as it supposed to start sever on localhost:3000 .

Comment: oh..i see.. after that i have to run `node server/server.js` and its running on localhost:3000